# Python password strength

Tags: python, passwords, numbers

I am programming a password strength code on python and i'm trying to find out if my password (`p`) contains a number, I have found out how to see if it contains upper and lower case letter by `p.isupper()` or `p.islower()`. I have also put them two together. My friend has told me how to see if the password only contains number but I need your help now.

```
running=True
while running:
    p=raw_input("What is your Password? ")
    if len(p) <6:
        print "Your Password is too short"
    if len(p) >12:
        print "Your Password is too long"
    if len(p) == 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:
        print "Password Length OK"
        running=False

print "Loop Broken" #this will be deleted, only for my help now

if p.isupper():
    print "Your Password is weak as it only contains capital letters"

if p.islower():
    print "Your Password is weak as it only contains lower case letters"

if p.isupper and p.islower:
    print "Your Password is of medium strength, try adding some numbers"

try:
    int(p)
    print "Your Password is weak as it only contains numbers"
except (ValueError, TypeError):
    pass
```

All I need now is the code for, if the password contains lower or upper case letters and numbers.

Comment: `len(p) == 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12:` should be `6<=len(p)<=12`

Comment: Why do you have upper limit of 12 chars in the password?

Comment: @user1615903 The task said to make a password checker and check if it is between 6 and 12 characters long

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To me, regex would definitely be the easiest way of going about this.

Given a sample password `password`, the way you would check it would be:

```py
import re
# Check if contains at least one digit
if re.search(r'\d', password):
    print "Has a digit"
# Check if contains at least one uppercase letter
if re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
    print "Has uppercase letter"
# Check if contains at least one lowercase letter
if re.search(r'[a-z]', password):
    print "Has lowercase letter"
```

For your other pieces, you can continue to use `.isupper()` and `.islower()`.

By the way, this portion of your code:

```py
if p.isupper and p.islower:
    print "Your Password is of medium strength, try adding some numbers"
```

Will not function how you want it to.  First, you're not actually calling the methods, since you haven't put the parentheses--you need to write `if p.isupper() and p.islower():`.  Second, this doesn't actually do what you want it to.  You're trying to check that it contains **both** lowercase and uppercase numbers.  Instead, you're checking both that it is completely uppercase *and* completely lowercase, and obviously it can't be both, so that if statement will always return `False`.  Instead, you'll want to use something like:

```py
if re.search(r'[a-z]', password) and re.search(r'[A-Z]', password):
```

Or, alternatively, without `re`:

```py
import string
if any(letter in string.ascii_lowercase for letter in password) and \
  any(letter in string.ascii_uppercase for letter in password):
```

Or:

```py
if any(letter.islower() for letter in password) and \
  any(letter.isupper() for letter in password):
```

I happen to prefer `re` because it's more concise.

Comment: Cheers mate, you've helped me out :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to check whether your password contains all of these : lowercase, uppercase and digits.

```
>>> from string import ascii_lowercase, ascii_uppercase, digits
>>> s_lc = set(ascii_lowercase)
>>> s_uc = set(ascii_uppercase)
>>> s_d = set(digits)
def func(strs):
    s = set(strs)
    return all(s & x for x in (s_lc,s_uc,s_d ))
... 
>>> func('fooBar09')
True
>>> func('fooBar')
False
>>> func('900')
False
>>> func('900aB')
True
```

Secondly `len (p) == 6 or 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12` is going to be evaluated as:

`(len(p) == 6) or 7` so if `len(p)` is 6 then it returns `True` else 7(which is a Truthy value  as well)

it should be : `if 6 <= len(p) <= 12`

```
>>> 7 or 8 or 9 or 10 or 11 or 12
    7
```

Use `while True` instead of using a flag variable, and  you need `if-elif-else` conditions here not `if-if`:

```
while True:
    p=raw_input("What is your Password? ")
    le = len(p)
    if le <6:
        print "Your Password is too short"
    elif le >12:
        print "Your Password is too long"
    elif 6 <= le <= 12:
        print "Password Length OK"
        break
```

Comment: i'd say 6 or 7 ... will return 7 which is True unless len(p) is actually 6 in which case it will return directly True. it is evaluated as `(len(p) == 6) or 7`

Comment: @njzk2 I totally missed the `len(p) ==` part, fixing it. :|