# Password Tester in Python

Tags: python

I am writing a program that is supposed to take a string (the password entered by user) and test it to make sure it meets the following requirements:
must contain at least one uppercase letter and one lowercase letter
must start with a letter
minimum of eight characters
no blanks
must contain at least two digits

this is what i have so far and I'm stuck getting invalid syntax errors
running = True

```
while running:
    valid = 0
    password = str("Enter Password: ")
    if len(p) <8:
        print ("The password you entered is too short. Please try again.")
        running = False
    import re

    #check if contains a digit
    if re.search(r '\d', password):
        password = valid

    #check if contains uppercase letter
    if re.search(r '[A-Z]', password):
         password = valid

    #check if contains lowercase letter
    if re.search(r '[a-z]', password):
        password = valid

    #check if contains only letters
    if re.search(r "[a-z]", password) and re.search(r "[A-Z]", password):
        print ("Password must contain at least 2 digits. Please try again.")

    #check if contains all lowercase letters
    if password.islower():
        print ("Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter. Please try again.")

    #check if contains all uppercase letters
    if password.isupper():
        print ("Password must contain at least 1 lowercase letter. Please try again.")

    if password == valid:
        print ("Valid Password")
```

Comment: the logic here doesnt work at all -- once you pass the first (digit) check you set password equal to "valid" (which is zero..).  You will then fail all the other tests (throw an error actually i think since re.search expects a string.

Comment: This is a dup of dozens of questions here. Did you try searching at all? In addition to the one I linked, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17105957/python-password-strength?rq=1) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16709638/checking-the-strength-of-a-password-how-to-check-conditions), and many of the related questions on those 3, and everything that comes up in a search for `[python] [passwords]`, and…

Comment: you think "make a password checker" is homework exercise 1 in chapter 2 of every python textbook..

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple problems with the code shown, in addition to the spacing error in your regexps, as mentioned by DevEight.

1) `password = str("Enter Password: ")` - this does not ask the user for a password, this sets the name `password` to refer to the string `"Enter Password: "`. You want `input` instead (or `raw_input` for Python version 2.x).

2) `if len(p) <8:` - `p` is not a defined name. Presumably you mean `password`.

3) `running = False` - this is the only place you set this variable, but it controls your `while` loop. Your loop only exits when this is `false`, so this will keep looping until the password is too short, whereup it will eventually exit.

4) `password = valid` - this sets the `password` name to refer to the contents of the variable `valid`, which you initialize to `0`. You then run further regular expression searches against the integer `0`, which are of course wrong.

5) `if re.search(r "[a-z]", password) and re.search(r "[A-Z]", password):` - this is commented to say that it requries that there be at least two numbers in the password. It doesn't. I have no idea why you might think it does.

6) `if password == valid:` - this kind of sort of works, in the sense that you may have previously set `password` to have the same value as `valid`. As mentioned above, that's wrong, but it means this could sometimes return `True`. With working code, you need completely different logic.

7) To top it all off, your question refers to syntax errors from `running = True` - but that assignment isn't present anywhere in the code.

On the up side, good use of `isupper` and `islower`. Those methods make your earlier upper and lowercase regexp searches unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to get the password from the user.

```
password = str("Enter the password")
```

should be:

```
password = raw_input("Enter the password")
```

Then, you are checking for valid conditions, which may cause logical errors. So, instead of checking if it satisfies all conditions, check if it does not satisfy any condition (ie) reverse of what you are doing right now..

Eg)

```
flag = 1

invalid = 0
if(len(password)<8):
    flag = 0
if password.islower():
    flag = 0
#all conditions
#at last, check for the flag value.
if flag:
    print "Password valid"
else:
    print "Password not valid"
```